# Does memory get automatically cleared in python Queues?

Tags: python, opencv, queue, rtsp

I have a python script (3.7.3) that uses OpenCV (4.1.1) with GStreamer backend to stream live RTSP URL.

After VideoCapture, frames are read and stored in a queue. The queue size is 10. If the queue gets full, the oldest frame is popped out and a new frame is pushed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from queue import Queue

q = Queue(10)
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp://url)
while True:
    status, image = vcap.read()
    print("READ IMAGE")
    if(status):
        if(q.full()):
            q.get()
            print("Skipping Queue")
        q.put({'image': np.array(image)})
    del image
```

What happens when I do **q.get()**? Does the frame gets deleted from memory after getting popped, or stays in memory? Or do I need to explicitly delete that by using del? I am observing memory usage increasing over time in my code